# nginx codeigniter subdomain gives error 500

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, subdomain

Alright,

So my main site, yorkdigitalsolutions.com is using codeigniter, on nginx and everything works perfectly, I got the redirect and all working perfect.

So I do the same for a codeigniter project I am working on, and I put it to my test subdomain etienne.yorkdigitalsolutions.com, and create the A zone like I should in Linode's dns manager and when I have just a flat html file, it all resolves and works nice, otherwise with the codeigniter project, I get error 500.

Where should I start looking for the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alright,

So it turns out that if you need something (like a database) and codeigniter does not have access to it, it will throw out error 500.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future